Split text into smaller one and group by each ID
I have an Excel table like this


Now from the second column, I want to split them into small substring and group them in each ID group, like this

Please let me know how I can do that programmatically.
Since I'm new from Excel, I have tried this but it does not work: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7

Please let me know how I can do that programmatically. Yes you can. One way would be to get all the data in an array and then loop and split values using ">" as a delim. Then simply reconstruct all possible combinatoons. Finally write the data to the worksheet.

use functions like left(), mid(), right() and find() to avoid vba.

Just going of the screenshots you have a newer version of Excel then 2010, let alone 2007. It would help to be concise in your tags since newer versions of Excel could possibly do this use formulae too. That said; if you want help, you should post the sample data in markdown format and include your own honest attempt at solving it.


Use two Collection objects to transform data

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, arrRes, aTxt, sTxt As String
    Dim idCol As New Collection, ruleCol As New Collection
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        aTxt = Split(arrData(i, 2), ">"): sTxt = ""
        For j = LBound(aTxt) To UBound(aTxt)
            idCol.Add arrData(i, 1)
            sTxt = sTxt & ">" & aTxt(j)
            ruleCol.Add Mid(sTxt, 2)
        Next j
    Next i
    ReDim arrRes(1 To idCol.Count, 1)
    For i = 1 To idCol.Count
        arrRes(i, 0) = idCol(i)
        arrRes(i, 1) = ruleCol(i)
    Next
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(idCol.Count, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub


Please, try using the next code. It should be very fast even for large ranges, using arrays and processing almost everything in memory.
The range to be processed should be in columns A:B and it returns starting from D2:
Sub splitRedistribute()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSpl, arrFin, prevStr As String
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on A:A column
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2 'place the range to be processed in an array for faster processing
  
  'load the dictionary with the necessary data:
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array rows:
    arrSpl = Split(arr(i, 2), " > ") 'obtain an array by splitting the B:B column content
    dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrSpl         'place the array as item of A:A key
    k = k + UBound(arrSpl) + 1       'variable use to know how many rows arrFin must have
  Next i
  
  ReDim arrFin(1 To k, 1 To 2):  k = 1 'Redim the final array and reuse k variable, reinitializing it
  'process the dictionary data and load arrFin:
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1 'iterate between the dictionary elements (key/items)
    prevStr = ""                              'renitialize the var which temp keeps the previous concatenated value
    For j = 0 To UBound(dict.Items()(i))
        arrFin(k, 1) = dict.keys()(i)         'place the key in array first column
        Select Case j                         'load the array second column according to iteration number
            Case 0
              arrFin(k, 2) = dict.Items()(i)(j) 'place the first array element
              prevStr = arrFin(k, 2): k = k + 1 'memorize the first element and increment the row var (k)
            Case Else
              arrFin(k, 2) = prevStr & " > " & dict.Items()(i)(j) 'place the concatenation in the second column
              prevStr = arrFin(k, 2): k = k + 1 'memorize the concatenated string to be used further and increment the row
        End Select
    Next j
  Next i
  
  'drop the processed array content, at once:
  sh.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
I commented the code but if something not clear enough, do  not hesitate to ask for clarifications.
As general recommendations, you should not paste pictures, try showing something editable to be used for testing and a piece of code showing your attempt will always be welcomed. Even if it does not do what you need... We can see the range you try processing, where you try returning etc.

If you have Excel 365 you can do this by formula:
=LET(data,A2:B5,
λHierarchy, LAMBDA(ID,Rule,
                LET(cntDel,LEN(Rule)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Rule,">",""))+1,
                    HSTACK( SEQUENCE(cntDel,,ID,0), 
                            TEXTBEFORE(Rule &" > "," > ",SEQUENCE(cntDel))))),
REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
          LAMBDA(result,i,VSTACK(result,
                                 λHierarchy(INDEX(data,i,1),INDEX(data,i,2)))
                    )
        )
)

λHierarchy uses TEXTBEFORE to create a row per hierarchy level and adds the ID before.

